# How to set unique column for specified enum in mysql and laravel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, time

My table is for time schedule from sunday to satureday ,
i want to make unique key that for sunday time 9 am can be unique but we can use time 9 am for another day in one table,
for example,

**day        |time**
sunday       |9.00 am
monday       |9.00 am
monday       |10.00 am
sunday       |9.00 am  -> this will be not okay

**my migration code is for doctor schedule:-**

```
Schema::create('doctorschedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->enum('dayid',["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]);
            $table->time('starttime');
            $table->time('endtime');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('dr_id');
            $table->foreign('dr_id')->references('id')->on('doctors');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

dayid is for day Sunday to Saturday

> **And also main thing is that user will not able to use in between time also like if start time is 9.00 and end time is 10.00 the userwill be not able to take start time 9.30
> so please share me logic if have**

Answer (score 0):

Example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (`day` ENUM('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Fri','Sat'), `time` CHAR(8));
> ```

> ```
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx 
> ON test ((CASE WHEN `day`='Sun' AND `time`='09:00 am' THEN 0 ELSE NULL END));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test VALUES 
> ('Sun', '09:00 am'),
> ('Sun', '10:00 am'),
> ('Mon', '09:00 am'),
> ('Mon', '10:00 am'),
> ('Mon', '09:00 am');     -- allowed duplicate
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> day | time    
> :-- | :-------
> Sun | 09:00 am
> Sun | 10:00 am
> Mon | 09:00 am
> Mon | 10:00 am
> Mon | 09:00 am
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test VALUES 
> ('Sun', '09:00 am');     -- non-allowed duplicate
> ```
>
> ```
> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'test.idx'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=534be69704cd2cc9c8c052b7c0c9a239)*

Map this to Laravel by yourself.